# How to specify the root directory of the http server

Tags: c#

I try to change a bit this http server , i have found this code at [github](https://github.com/paulpjoby/Simple-HTTP-Server-Using-Visual-C-Sharp)

In this example it show the time-server but i want to specified the root directory of the html or code. i have try to change the line were is the html code and change it by the link of the root but it give me this error.
How can i change it ?
This is the error

> Error 4   Unrecognized escape sequence    C:\Users\MDLABS\Desktop\Simple-HTTP-Server-Using-Visual-C-Sharp-main\SimpleHTTPServer\Form1.cs  140 38  SimpleHTTPServer

This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace SimpleHTTPServer
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Socket httpServer;
    private int serverPort = 80;
    private Thread thread;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void startServerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serverLogsText.Text = "";

        try
        {
            httpServer = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                serverPort = int.Parse(serverPortText.Text.ToString());

                if(serverPort > 65535 || serverPort <= 0)
                {
                   throw new Exception("Server Port not within the range");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                serverPort = 80;
                serverLogsText.Text = "Server Failed to Start on Specified Port \n";
            }

            thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.connectionThreadMethod));
            thread.Start();

            // Disable and Enable Buttons
            startServerBtn.Enabled = false;
            stopServerBtn.Enabled = true;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error while starting the server");
            serverLogsText.Text = "Server Starting Failed \n";
        }

        serverLogsText.Text = "Server Started";
    }

    private void stopServerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Close the Socket
            httpServer.Close();

            // Kill the Thread
            

            // Disable and Enable Buttons
            startServerBtn.Enabled = true;
            stopServerBtn.Enabled = false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stopping Failed");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopServerBtn.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void connectionThreadMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, serverPort);
            httpServer.Bind(endpoint);
            httpServer.Listen(1);
            startListeningForConnection();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I could nt start");
        }
    }

    private void startListeningForConnection()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

            String data = "";
            byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];

            Socket client = httpServer.Accept(); // Blocking Statement

            // Reading the inbound connection data
            while (true)
            {
                int numBytes = client.Receive(bytes);
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, numBytes);

                if (data.IndexOf("\r\n") > -1)
                    break;
            }

            // Data Read

            serverLogsText.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                // Runs inside the UI Thread
                serverLogsText.Text += "\r\n\r\n";
                serverLogsText.Text += data;
                serverLogsText.Text += "\n\n------ End of Request -------";
            });

            // Send back the Response
            String resHeader = "HTTP/1.1 200 Everything is Fine\nServer: my_csharp_server\nContent-Type: text/html; charset: UTF-8\n\n";
            String resBody = "C:\Program Files\Ampps\www";

            String resStr = resHeader + resBody;

            byte[] resData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(resStr);

            client.SendTo(resData, client.RemoteEndPoint);

            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `thread.Abort();` - throw this piece of garbage to the curb and find a better example to build upon.

Comment: @Fildor i have all ready taked out but the line of thhe error is this one `code` String resBody = "C:\Program Files\Ampps\www";

Comment: Yes. "\" is indicating an escape sequence like in "\n". You need to de-escape it. But that's your smallest issue with this. I have two hard red flag indicators for "do not use this": 1. Usage of Goto and Labels. 2. Thread.Abort().

Comment: ^^ "De-Escaping" - by that I mean, you need to tell C# that this is _not_ meant to be an escape-sequence. You'd usually do this by using the [verbatim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) : @"C:\..." or double the indicator as in "C:\\Program..."

Comment: @Fildor Tank you for help , i did the change but the error continue

Comment: When you change that line to: `String resBody = @"C:\Program Files\Ampps\www";` you should not have the **same** error....

Comment: What is your goal in this and why does your _server_ actually have a "Form"? If this is merely for learning purposes: Maybe take a smaller step. Get familiar with string manipulation etc ... then return to this.

Comment: @Fildor My Goal its to make server to show any page code in folder, but on this case i get only the string and not the index.php or what ever code page is in side

Comment: @Fildor https://imgur.com/MeiSlSW here is the print from what i get, https://imgur.com/MeiSlSW